# Convolution of two functions (pdfs)

Tags: probability, convolution

I want to convolve two signals . The range of each of the signal is 0 to 1.

```
                             y1={1/(y1)0.5} -1
                             y2={1/(y2)0.5} -1
                             z=y1+y2
```

I want to convolve the above two signals.Basically the above two are pdfs.I want to find the pdf of the sum of the above two pdfs.So, I need to convolve the above two pdfs.

I want to know what should be the range for the convolution in my case.Secondly,Convolving above two will result some terms in Z.Am I doing right.Please help me out as I am weak in convolution.

Comment: Are your density functions of shape $\dfrac{1}{y^{0.5}}-1$ on $(0,1)$?

Comment: Hi Zara, welcome to math.SE. You've now asked five different questions that all seem to deal with very similar and/or related problems, and your difficulties in deriving the results yourself also seem to be similar. May I suggest that you try to abstract from these examples, stop posting further examples, at least for now, and instead try to pinpoint what it is that's causing you trouble and ask about it in a more general form? I think that would be better both for you and for the contribution it makes to this site.